# AND gate, red wires logisim

Tags: logisim

I have these and gates. When I disconnect one of the red wires from its corresponding gate, the other goes green. But if they're both connected it goes red. From what I've read in the documentation, this means this carries an error value, but I don't see how that could be the case here. I'm just working with this as a subcircuit, so I know the exact values going in that cause a problem - which is, if get or set = 1, these two AND gates turn red.

Any suggestions for debugging?

[image]

Comment: You probably need to show the other things those wires are connected to.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something (that isn't in your picture) is either connecting those two wires together, or is connecting them to another output.

Disconnect it.